# How to stop my camera after it reaches it's target

Tags: javascript, animation, math, camera

I have a simple function which the user can click and drag the camera. The camera moves with a slight smoothness, but i do not know a simple way to stop the camera once it has caught up to the mouse position.

I'm sure it's just a simple maths logic error, but currently the camera just keeps floating off forever.

This is my function:

```
function drag(evt,el){
    clearInterval(timer);
    if(evt.button == 2){ //right click and drag
    mousePos = {};
    mousePos.x = evt.offsetX / scale;
    mousePos.y = evt.offsetY / scale;
    function update(e){
        var difx    = mousePos.x - (e.offsetX/scale),
            dify    = mousePos.y - (e.offsetY/scale);
        var targetX = camera.x + difx;
        var targetY = camera.y + dify;

        //update for next mouse movement
        mousePos.x  = e.offsetX / scale;
        mousePos.y  = e.offsetY / scale;     

        function smooth(){ // the problems lay here
            if(camera.x != targetX){
                camera.x    += (difx * lerp);
            }
            if(camera.y != targetY){
                camera.y    += (dify * lerp);
            }
        }

        timer = setInterval(smooth,16);
    }           
    function clear(){
        el.removeEventListener('mousemove', update, false);
        this.removeEventListener('mouseup', clear, false);
    }
    el.addEventListener('mousemove',update,false);
    document.body.addEventListener('mouseup',clear,false);  
}}
```

I have the code in action here **http://jsfiddle.net/bbb9q2c3/** if you click and drag then let go the box will keep moving because my current code does not seem to detect when the camera has reached it's target.

What can i do to solve this issue?

Comment: I played around with this for a bit and didnt get a working solution. Here's some things I noted. The camera will never exactly match the target. I suggest adding a buffer and checking if it lies within the bound.  Secondly, I used setTimeout instead of setInterval, that way once smooth was met, I used clearTimeout so the function wouldn't run indefinitely.

Comment: Is there a way to guarentee it will hit the target positions perhaps using a sorta of deltaTime situation ?

Comment: Are you calling `setInterval()` without clearing it ever on mousemove? Bad idea...

Comment: @Kaiido oh i forgot to add that! Thanks for spotting it.

Comment: @Dave what about if the delta is negative testing to see if the position is less than the target, and if its positive testing to see if the position is greater than the target.

Comment: @cgatian because you can go left which is a positive direction or right which is a negative direction

Comment: Right, only check the one or the other based on the direction of movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/cqxf0a73/2/) with this a bit.

Here's what I changed:

1. In the draw function I removed translate, so that the camera coordinates match mouse coordinates. So camera with (0,0) is at the top left and not middle.
2. Use threshold to check if camera is near the mouse `ath.abs(dify) > 1`.
3. Added clearInterval to update function. It is less responsive now, so you may want to fiddle with that.
4. Set square to the middle position in the initialization.

Comment: It's not quite the behaviour i was looking for, it shouldn't go to where the mouse position is but rather move the same amount as the mouse did. So if the mouse moved up 1 px so should the camera. Also it gets very jittery if I have it only delay for like > 0.1 for example. So if i wanted a 10 ms delay it goes very odd.

Comment: Oh, I see. When does the camera stop? Lets say mouse went 10px up and then 10px left and camera is lagging behind - only went 8px up. When does it turn left and when does it stop?

Comment: It can turn sooner as long as its final target is still relatively the same distance as the same distance that the mouse moved overall, otherwise the further you scroll the less accurate the camera movement is to the mouse. In other words, it doesn't need to follow the path strictly, i was aiming for a delay a like 100 milliseconds, so it would barely be noticeable anyway.